# Regex sed problems

Tags: regex, sed

```
ls June/frx*|sed 's/_generate_backtest_forward_starting.csv//g'|sed -s 's/June\///g'

frxAUDJPY
frxAUDUSD
frxEURAUD
frxEURCAD
frxEURGBP
frxEURJPY
frxEURNOK


ls June/frx*|sed 's/_generate_backtest_forward_starting.csv//g'|sed -s 's/June|April\///g'

June/frxAUDJPY
June/frxAUDUSD
June/frxEURAUD
June/frxEURCAD
June/frxEURGBP
June/frxEURJPY
```

First one works , second one doesn't. Why doesn't it see the OR (|) in between June and April?

Comment: figured it out....somehow silly sed requires.... \|                   ls June/frx*|sed 's/_generate_backtest_forward_starting.csv//g'|sed -s 's/June\/\|April\///g'

Comment: not possible to use a `|` (or) with the native reduce RegEx. GNU sed allow this with the option `-r` for the extended-Regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the `\`. You'll find a good explanation [in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32907/what-characters-do-i-need-to-escape-when-using-sed-in-a-sh-script).

Answer (score 0):

You can either escape `|` or use `GNU sed`'s `-r` option:

```
$ echo 'June/frxAUDJPY' | sed -r 's_(June|April)/__g'
frxAUDJPY
```